# why my kalman's cov-pre and cov-post keep increasing

Tags: computer-vision, kalman-filter, slam-algorithm

[image: cov in the frame 70 , now the cov is acceptable]
cov in the frame 70 , now the cov is acceptable

[image]
cov in the frame 82 , as you can find , after update step , the cov in the diagonal could be decrease , but the bottom left is keeping increasing , and it would make the cov-pre very big in next step , then the system corrupt , anyone could help me for this :)

Comment: I should remind that the 9 states is [ x-trans, y-trans, z-trans, x-rot, y-rot,z-rot, x-trans-speed, y-trans-speed,z-trans-speed] with right sequence :)

Comment: If you are printing out the state covariance matrix then you have big problems. The covariance matrix should be symmetrical, and postive definite. What you show isn't either of those!

Comment: ok thank you for your attention :) I will check more

Comment: @dmuir I have a question ? , should all the number in covariance should be positive or only the number in diagonal should be positive ? and is it should be symmetric ? I think in the update step P = (I - KH)P may make the P not symmetric

Comment: In the update step K = PH'R where R = inv( I + H*P*H') (which is symmetric)  so the new P is P - PH'RHP which is symmetric, If your implementation uses (I-KH)P then rounding error may induce some asymmetry but in your printout above P is so grossly anti symmetric (after relatively few steps) that I'd be surprised if that's the only  culprit.

Comment: Being positive definite implies that all diagonal elements are positive, but that is not sufficient. Kalman filters can be very susceptible to rounding error . The square root form is worth a look, google it.

Comment: thank you for your patience :)